# Using function as another function input

Tags: c++, function, arguments

Hi I'm quite new to coding yet I have a quite complex pshysics problem to solve with cpp and I've encountered some problems

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double delta_x(double x, double n)
{
    return x/n;
}

double theta(delta_x(double x,double n),double i, double a)
{
    return atan(abs(2*a*((delta_x(x,n)*i)-50)-(0.01)));
}
```

Codeblox givex me following errors:

```
|9|error: expected primary-expression before 'double'|
|9|error: expected primary-expression before 'double'|
|9|error: expected primary-expression before 'double'|
|9|error: expected primary-expression before 'double'|
|9|error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]|
|10|error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token|
|20|error: 'theta' cannot be used as a function|
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have to pass `delta_x` again. Just put simply: `double theta(double i, double a)`. It should work.

Comment: Read a good book like "C++ Primer 5th edition" before attempting to solve complex problems - using functions is part of the basics you should know

Comment: I wouldn't do it but it's part of my phsycics exercise which I need to do for thursday sooo I don't think I have enough time do read anything at that point

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to pass `delta_x` back into `theta`:

```
double delta_x(double x, double n)
{
    return x/n;
}

double theta(double i, double a)
{
    return atan(abs(2*a*((delta_x(i,a)*i)-50)-(0.01)));
}
```

Comment: actually as a `delta_x` paramteres I need `x` and `n` which initialized in `int main()` later

Comment: @TheRlee: write a minimal example representing your use case in your question

Comment: so i need this part of program to read some `n` value, calculate `delta_x` for this `n` and then to use this `delta_x` calculating `theta` for some `a` and `i`

Comment: @TheRlee: open a new question with a minimal example showing how you want to call `theta`.

Comment: i managed to solve the problem myself, but certainly that's not my last problem with this homework :/ anyway thanks for help